# User input cannot be used more than once to search a txt file

Tags: python-2.7

Hello fellow community,

First off, thank you for looking into my question.

I have a seperate text file called lions.txt which holds the following data:

**The lion (Panthera leo) is one of the big cats in the genus Panthera and a member of the family Felidae. The commonly used term African lion collectively denotes the several subspecies in Africa.**

**With some males exceeding=250kg (550 lb) in weight,[4] it is the second-largest living cat after the tiger, the lion is an awesome cat.**

The issue that I have is that I have created two functions. Each function takes in the users requested keyword to search, and if both keywords are in the same sentence then python will paste all sentences that have both the keywords into a seperate file called txtfile.txt - The issue is if I run one function it will find ALL the sentences based on the two keywords and paste it into the txtfile.txt. If I then run the second function and comment out the first function out it will also find ALL the sentence based on the keywords specified by the user. However, if I uncomment both of them then only the function which is at the top of the list will have ALL its sentences found and pasted to txtfile.txt

Example:

```
import re
import os

os.chdir("C:\Python 2016 Training")  # Changes directory to the following path
what_directory_am_i_in = os.getcwd()  # Variable holds the directory path 
print what_directory_am_i_in  # Prints what directory the user is in so they can confirm they are in the correct location

patterns = open("lions.txt", "r") #Opens the file we are searching through

shep = open('txtfile.txt', "w") # Creates the file 

search = raw_input("What you looking for? ") # Takes in user input that will be used to search in the searchtext() function and kev() function

print search

def searchtext():
    for line in patterns:
        if search in line and "family" in line:
            shep.write(line)
            shep.write("\n")


def kev():
        shep.write('\n')
        for id in patterns:
            match = re.search('exceeding=(\d+)', id)
            if match and search in id:
                shep.write("\n")
                shep.write("THIS IS THE SECOND FUNCTION")
                shep.write(id)          


searchtext()
kev()
```

If I comment out searchtext() and have the user enter Keyword lion it will copy paste the following to txtfile.txt "THIS IS THE SECOND FUNCTIONWith some males lion exceeding=250kg (550 lb) in weight,[4] it is the second-largest living cat after the tiger, the lion is an awesome cat."

If I uncomment both and type lion it will print out the first sentence and not the second "The lion (Panthera leo) is one of the big cats in the genus Panthera and a member of the family Felidae. The commonly used term African lion collectively denotes the several subspecies in Africa."

Ultimately the end goal is to be able to call each function individually and if the keywords are in a sentence then Python should paste all the sentences that have those keywords in them to txtfile.txt.

Thank you so much for your help. I suspect my code is overwriting itself, but im not sure.

Regards,
Kevin

Comment: the open() function return a handler to the file pointing at the beginning of the file. Once you iterate on the file in your searchtext(), your pointer has already reached the end. Hence your second function does not work. The pointer - patterns has reached the end of file.

Comment: Thanks Renuka, do you have any suggestions on how I can work around this?

Comment: why dont you try combining the 2 functions into one ? you can have both your if cases in one function.

Comment: Hi Renuka, the reason is that I plan on using Tkinter and mapping each function to a button as a event handler. Based on which button that is pressed by the user should trigger the function. I would like for the user to select both buttons at different times and then the functions should populate txtfile.txt with the desired search.

Comment: Use [`file_object.seek(0)`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) to move the file pointer back to the beginning of the file before attempting to read from it again.

Comment: Ok cool, let me try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use file_object.seek(0) to move the file pointer back to the beginning of the file before attempting to read from it again. – pzp